# Printing a column in an matrix without numpy

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I'm really new to programming, so I apologize if this is a really simple question, but i've been trying to print the first column in a matrix without the use of numpy, however it prints like so:

```
matrix = \
[[0, 1],
 [3, 7],
 [9, 4],
 [10, 3]]

print matrix[0:3][0]
[0, 1]
```

I've also tried:

```
print matrix[:][0]
[0, 1]

print matrix[:3]
[[0, 1], [3, 7], [9, 4]]

print matrix[:3][0]
[[0, 1], [3, 7], [9, 4]]
```

The answer I'm trying to achieve is:

```
print matrix[code]
0, 3, 9, 10
```

or similar.

Comment: I'm unsure why you thought `matrix[:3]` should print the result you gave - the slicing syntax is `slicable[start:stop:step]`, (defaulting to 0, len(slicable) and 1 respectively if not given), so `[:3]` means, starting at 0, stopping at 3.

Comment: Ah, too true. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is a list of lists - so there is no concept of a column there. There are two ways to do this, one is (as [Pavel Anossov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15937962/722121) shows) is to use a list comprehension.

One is to use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) which can be used to transpose an iterable:

```
>>> list(zip(*matrix))
[(0, 3, 9, 10), (1, 7, 4, 3)]
```

I've made it a list here to make it easier to show the output. Note in 2.x, `zip()` gives a list rather than an iterator (although a lazy version is available as [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)).

Generally, I would use `zip()` if you plan on working with more than one column, and the list comprehension if you only need one.

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible with slicing without numpy. You can use a list comprehension:

```
print [row[0] for row in matrix]
```